Gulp, обработка шрифтов
Почему выполняя эту задачу Gulp сохраняет шрифты woff2 там, где прписано (в папке /dist/fonts), но шрифты woff сохраняются в корне собранного проекта (папка /dist)?
export const otfToTtf = () => {
  // Ищем файлы шрифтов .otf
  return app.gulp.src(`${app.path.srcFolder}/fonts/*.otf`, {})
    .pipe(app.plugins.plumber(
      app.plugins.notify.onError({
        title: 'FONTS',
        message: 'Error: <%= error.message %>'
      })
    ))
    // Конвертируем в .ttf
    .pipe(fonter({
      formats: ['ttf']
    }))
    // Выгружаем в исходную папку
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(`${app.path.srcFolder}/fonts/`))
}

export const ttfToWoff = () => {
  return app.gulp.src(`${app.path.srcFolder}/fonts/*.ttf`)
    .pipe(app.plugins.plumber(
      app.plugins.notify.onError({
        title: 'FONTS',
        message: 'Error: <%= error.message %>'
      })
    ))
    // Конвертируем в .woff
    .pipe(fonter({ formats: ['woff'] }))
    // Сохраняем woff в нужную папку
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.fonts))

    .pipe(app.gulp.src(`${app.path.srcFolder}/fonts/*.ttf`))
    // Конвертируем в .woff2
    .pipe(ttf2woff2())
    // Сохраняем woff2 в ту же папку
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.fonts));
}

файл path.js:
// Получаем имя папки проекта
import * as nodePath from 'path'
const rootFolder = nodePath.basename(nodePath.resolve())

const buildFolder = `./dist`
const srcFolder = `./src`

export const path = {
  build: {
    js: `${buildFolder}/js/`,
    css: `${buildFolder}/css/`,
    html: `${buildFolder}/`,
    images: `${buildFolder}/images/`,
    fonts: `${buildFolder}/fonts/`,
    files: `${buildFolder}/files/`,
  },
  src: {
    js: `${srcFolder}/js/app.js`,
    images: `${srcFolder}/images/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,webp}`,
    svg: `${srcFolder}/images/**/*.svg`,
    scss: `${srcFolder}/scss/style.scss`,
    html: `${srcFolder}/*.html`,
    files: `${srcFolder}/files/**/*.*`,
    svgicons: `${srcFolder}/svgicons/*.svg`,
  },
  watch: {
    js: `${srcFolder}/js/**/*.js`,
    scss: `${srcFolder}/scss/**/*.scss`,
    html: `${srcFolder}/**/*.html`,
    images: `${srcFolder}/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,svg,gif,webp,ico}`,
    files: `${srcFolder}/files/**/*.*`
  },
  clean: buildFolder,
  buildFolder: buildFolder,
  srcFolder: srcFolder,
  rootFolder: rootFolder,
  ftp: `test`
}

